# Rails custom update action generates get request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip to store images for records called 'Expense' - images are of receipts for the expense.

Everything works find, but when I go to edit an expense, I want to have a link to delete the image associated with that expense, so in my expense_controller, I have:

```
def delete_receipt_img
  @expense = Expense.find(params[:id])
  @expense.receipt_img.destroy
  @expense.receipt_img.clear

  @expense.save

  redirect_to edit_expense_path(params[:id])
end
```

I generate the view of the edit expense page with a partial that displays the delete link only if an image is associated with the expense:

```
<% if @expense.id.nil? || !@expense.receipt_img.file? %>
    <%= f.label :attach_receipt %><br/>
    <%= f.file_field :receipt_img %>
<% else %>
    <%= image_tag @expense.receipt_img.url %>
    <%= link_to "Delete Receipt", 
                delete_receipt_img_expense_url(@expense.id), 
                :method => :put %>
<% end %>
```

In my routes file, I followed an example from the Rails routing guide, and created the link like this:

```
resources :expenses do
  member do
   put 'delete_receipt_img'
  end
end
```

When I go to the the edit expense page, I see the "delete receipt" link is generated as such:

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/expenses/1/delete_receipt_img" data-method="put" rel="nofollow">Delete Receipt</a>
```

So it *looks* like everything is fine, but when I click the link, I get a routing error:

> **Routing Error**
>
> No route matches [GET] "/expenses/1/delete_receipt_img"
>
> Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

I can't figure out where this GET request is coming from! Ideas?

Comment: According to the doc for `link_to`, adding `:method => :put` will generate a form (which is required in order to execute a non-GET request).  That doesn't appear to be happening.  Check here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: I have read that. I even checked to see if I had Javascript disabled (under which condition, it'll default to GET), but it's not disabled.